# How can I create oracle view to be dynamic?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, view

```
create or replace view as
(select emp,department,salary
   from employee
   where partition_key = to_char(add_months(sysdate,-2) 'yyyymm'));
```

I have this view, where I get 2 months before data from employee table on 5th day of every month.

How can I use the same view to get last month's data like below from 10th day of every month.

```
create or replace view as
(select emp,department,salary
   from employee
   where partition_key = to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1) 'yyyymm'));
```

### EDIT

From comments:

Basically, for the first 10 days of a month, I want to see 2 months before data and from 10th night, I want to see last month data.

Comment: Change the `sysdate` ? That's not a serious suggestion.  What do you really want to do?  The question is unclear.

Comment: for example.. till 5th november 2015, I want to take september 2015 data from employee table(employee table is a huge monthly partition table) in my view.. and on 10th november 2015, I want to see october 2015 data.. Is it possible?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the actual select are useless (and just add unnecessary noise to the statement).

Comment: @Spider - what would you expect to see between 05-Nov and 10-Nov?

Comment: @BobJarvis - 05-Nov to 10-Nov, I want to see Sept data.. Every month 10th in the night I will schedule my job.. and on 10th Nov I want to see Oct data..

Comment: @BobJarvis - Basically, for the first 10 days of a month, I want to see 2 months before data and from 10th night, I want to see last month data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated requirements it appears that the following will accomplish what you want:

```
create or replace view as
  select emp, department, salary
    from employee
    where partition_key =
            to_char(add_months(sysdate,
                               CASE
                                 WHEN TO_NUMBER(TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD'))) <= 10
                                   THEN -2
                                 ELSE -1
                               END), 'yyyymm');
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Perhaps `extract(day from sysdate)` instead of `TO_NUMBER(TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD')))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could subtract 10 days from the current date ...

```
create or replace view blah
as
select
  emp,
  department,
  salary
from
  employee
where
  partition_key = to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate-10,'mm'),-1) 'yyyymm'));
```